# less.css: escape interpolated string for multiple selectors

Tags: less, mapnik

[ ANSWERED: the carto.css compiler does not support this feature of less.css]

I'm making a stylesheet for [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) that will be processed with [Carto](http://mapbox.com/carto/api/2.1.0/) (an extension of less.css). In other words, I'm making a stylesheet with LESS that uses some custom syntax.

I have a lists of selectors assigned to variables as strings, like so:

```
@water: "[natural='water'], [waterway='river'], [waterway='stream'], [waterway='waterfall'], [waterway='canal'], [landuse='reservoir'], [landuse='basin'], [amenity='pool'], [amenity='swimming_pool'], [amenity='fountain']"; 

@dirt: "[natural='beach'], [natural='sand'], [natural='scree'], [landuse='bedrock outcrop'], [landuse='quarry'], [natural='land'], [amenity='track']";
```

I want to be able to use these as selectors in my style sheet, more or less like this (which doesn't work):

`(~'@{water}') {
    polygon-fill: #bbb;
    }`

What I want to end up in my stylesheet is this:

`[natural='water'], [waterway='river'], [waterway='stream'], [waterway='waterfall'], [waterway='canal'], [landuse='reservoir'], [landuse='basin'], [amenity='pool'], [amenity='swimming_pool'], [amenity='fountain']{
    polygon-fill: #bbb;
}`

And I'm hoping there's a way to join selector groups, like this:

`@water, @dirt {
   polygon-fill: #bbb;
}`

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Interesting--when I use your solution on [this less compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) it works as you expect.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I suppose it could be that the compiler forked for Carto is not up to date

Comment: or the problem could be elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it could be that... or they did not implement that part of LESS in their code because of other stuff they are doing. Hard to say, but it does seem to point to something with the Carto compiler. One good thing about you having this issue is I learned about TileMill, that's cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the carto.css compiler does not support this feature of less.css](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues/1824#issuecomment-10769872)